# http streaming using java servlet

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet based web application which produces two sets of data. One set of data in the webpage which is essential and other set which is optional. I would like to render the essential data as fast as possible and then stream the optional data. I was thinking of writing the essential data to the output stream of `HttpServletRequest` and then call `HttpServletRequest.flushBuffer()` to commit the response to the client, but do not return from the servlet code, but instead create the optional data , write that to the outputstream again and then return from servlet code.
What are the things that could go wrong in this scheme ? Is this a standard practice to achieve this goal?

Comment: What kind of data is it? HTML?

Comment: yes its a normal HTML page which has js,css and html.

Answer (score 1):

It makes somewhat sense to flush the response buffer directly between `</head>` and `<body>` so that the browser retrieves references to JS/CSS resources as fast as possible. It only doesn't make sense to do it in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) as it's the [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) who is [supposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to be used to generate HTML.

```
</head>
<% response.flushBuffer(); %>
<body>
```

*(that's one of the 0.01% cases where using a scriptlet is forgiveable as there's no tag which does that; only in EL 2.2 you could use `${pageContext.response.flushBuffer()}`)*

However, most servletcontainers by default already flush the buffer every 2KB and that'll surely cover the entire `<head>` on the average webapp. You can finetune the response buffer size in server configuration (refer server documentation for details) or on a per-JSP basis using as follows:

```
<%@page buffer="1kb" %>
```

Further, flushing the buffer halfway a HTML `<body>` makes little to no sense as you're dependent on the browser whether it would render a halfbaked HTML body or not. MSIE for example displays nothing until the `</body>` is arrived.

A completely different alternative is to use JS/Ajax to load the "optional" content asynchronously in the background when the page is completed loading. E.g. (jQuery flavored):

```
$(function() {
    $("#somediv").load("somefragment.jsp");
});
```

#### See also:

- [Web application performance tips and tricks](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

Comment: I know that Ajax method is probably the best option however, there is only one thing that was holding me back from this approach and that is, if I go for Ajax method, the number of requests on my tomcat web server will become twice. And I am not sure there will be some infrastructure issues with that.

Comment: So, resourse requests like CSS/JS/images are not worth worrying? Sorry, but your concerns makes no sense. With ajax, the bandwidth is just split over multiple requests on the **same** connection. Measuring is knowing.

Comment: Resources requests are worth worrying and that is why they are served from CDN domains like akami.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this instead :

- return essential data as normal servlet + javascript to do Ajax calling for optional data. Then essential data will be shown with out wait the optional data.

so the html will look like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
        essential data
        <javascript to do ajax call>
        essential data
   </body>
</html>
```